# Bootstrap Tour n.popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a bootstrap tour but when i check the javascript i get

> `n.popover is not a function` from  bootstrap-tour.min.js

I try to fix it since 2 days it's a nightmare ...

Hope someone could help me .. thanks a lot in advance

Here my code :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="startTour">Start tour</a>

<div class="col-md-5" id="tour1" data-toggle="popover">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nom </label>
       {!! Form::text('lb_nom', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nom']) !!}
      </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5" id="tour2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Prénom </label>
    {!! Form::text('lb_prenom', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Prénom']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here my script :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ns3005219.ip-151-80-34.eu/licences/public/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css" />
<script src="http://ns3005219.ip-151-80-34.eu/licences/public/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Instance the tour
    var tour = new Tour({
        steps: [{
            element: "#tour1",
            title: "Exam Enrolment",
            content: "First let's enrol to an exam"
        }, {
            element: "#tour2",
            title: "Your Schedule",
            content: "Great, let's see your new schedule."
        }]
    }).init().start(true);

    $("#startTour").click(function(){
        tour.restart();

        console.log(tour);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You have to use bootstrap tour standalone files if you are using bootstrap
>   tour without bootstrap core files

I have made fiddle for you.

Check : https://jsfiddle.net/hgfcbhas/

Include

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

Rest of your code is correct